# restore MariaDB on Ec2 (not RDS) from S3 backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, mariadb, snapshot

I have a snapshot of a MariaDB and a folder with the corresponding images on S3.

I would like to launch an Ec2 to run the Mariadb snapshot I have on S3.

- Should I launch an Ec2, install MariaDB and then somehow import the data from the snapshot?

I found plenty of litereature on [how to restore a snapshot into RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html), but it usually refers to RDS snapshot, not a snapshot from S3. I could not find how to lunch a db on a ec2 from a S3 snapshot.

Comment: and the snapshot is what? is it like a whole disk image or is it something like /var/lib/mysql copy or is it mysqldump?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing S3 snapshot means SQL dump file. Here is the command you need to use.

The prerequisite is you need to have an EC2 with the Maria DB software installed.

And attach the IAM role to EC2 with s3 read permissions to read files from S3. Then run the below command.

```
mysql -u db_user -ppassword database_name < aws s3 cp s3://mysqldump_bucket_name/mysqldump.sql -
```